# Getting Chef to install, configure and run RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, chef-infra, cookbook

I am trying to get a simple, single instance of [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com) running via this [RabbitMQ-chef recipe](https://github.com/jjasghar/rabbitmq). Essentially, I have an Ubuntu machine, and I’d like Chef to take care of all the heavy lifting necessary to install, configure and get RabbitMQ running on it.

The documentation isn’t really written for beginners, but I went ahead and started by downloading the cookook:

```
knife cookbook site download rabbitmq
WARNING: No knife configuration file found
Downloading rabbitmq from the cookbooks site at version 4.1.2 to /Users/myuser/sandbox/chef/0.6.2/rabbitmq-4.1.2.tar.gz
Cookbook saved: /Users/myuser/sandbox/chef/0.6.2/rabbitmq-4.1.2.tar.gz
```

However now I’m at a complete loss as to what I need to script/configure in order to add this cookbook to my Chef server, such that when I SSH onto my target Ubuntu machine, I can bootstrap that machine with Chef and then run *something* to turn the Ubuntu machine into a RabbitMQ server. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you configure your own server or are you using Chef Manager (hosted service) like in the tutorials?

Comment: Thanks @SQDK (+1) - I configured my own Chef server

Comment: Alright, i have only used Chef Manager, so my knowledge is limited as to how the server part works. But knife expects a directory structure (the chef-repo) that includes a knife.rb containing information that is used to authenticate against the server. It seems like you are not using knife inside the chef-repo folder. When using Chef Manager, it is possible to download a starter-kit that contains a knife.rb file and the correct certificates. I don't know if there is such feature in open source chef. You can find a template for a chef-repo here: https://github.com/chef/chef-repo

Comment: The command you used only worked because it doesn't communicate with the server. It simply downloads a tar of the cookbook. When you have the folder structure in place, untar the file you downloaded and put it inside chef-repo/cookbooks/. You should now be able to use `knife cookbook upload {name of cookbook}` when inside the chef-repo directory. This will upload the cookbook to chef-server and it can now be used by other recipes or included in runlist.